# Find the coordinates of the point where r(t) = (2+t)i + (1-2t)j + 3t k intersects the yz plane?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis

I don't think it's a matter of simple 1 - 2t = 0, 3t = 0, because then there are two values of t.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Please help, this is the last time I will not use MathJax @Shaun

Comment: Better to do it now than postponing it for next time. You just need to put `$$` around your math.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the $yz$-plane is the set
$$\{(0,y,z)\mid y,z \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
so to find the intersection, set the $x$-component to $0$, and solve for $t$.